# Reordering methods using vim

Tags: vim

I have 2 methods in a source file:

```
def Foo
  puts "hello"
  puts "bar" 
end 

def Bar
  puts "hello"
  puts "bar" 
end
```

I would like to swap the order of the methods, so Bar is first.

Assuming the cursor is on the d in `def Foo`, the simple way is to:

```
shift v -> jjjj -> d -> jjj -> p -> O -> esc
```

But that feels a little long winded and does not account well for arbitrarily long methods:

What is the most efficient way to do this in Vim, keystroke wise?

**EDIT**
Keep in mind, I would like the solution to account for a situation where the methods are in a context of a big class, so <kbd>G</kbd> is probably best avoided

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming the cursor is somewhere in the first method, press `dap}p` and they should be swapped.

What `dap` does is simply "delete a paragraph". Try `:help object-select` to learn other way of deleting/selecting text objects in VIM.

**EDIT:** Replaced `G` with `}` in the command.

Comment: +1 for complete awesomeness, is there a way to solve this without the G key? so it works in context of a big class

Comment: Also can you explain dap? I can see what it does, but do not follow what it means.

Comment: You can use `dap}p` (replace `G` with `}` to move to the next method instead of the end of the file, and thus handle the situation where there is more code after the second method.

Comment: Awesome answer, you are my new vim guru :P

Comment: Wow again. Ignore every comment I've made, I'm a mouse among giants

Comment: Explaining dap:

The 'a' character, in visual mode or after an operator, allows you to select an object. p stands for paragraph, so dap = delete a paragraph. You could say das to delete a sentence, and so on. Look up text object selection in vim help for more.

Comment: Very cool... but if there are any empty lines in a method, `dap` won't select the entire method. Still, +1 for reminding me that I'm totally in a vim rut and need to start spending 15 minutes a day with the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Spatz's

```
d}}p
```

delete to the next blank line (below Foo), skip to the next blank line (below Bar), paste.

Answer (score 2):

Found another method ( from godlygeek on #vim ):

with:

```
def function():
    first
    first
    first

def lol():
    second
    second
    second
```

From line 1, count up until the 'def lol', which is 5. Then:

```
:1,5m$
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways off the top of my head. You could say

5dd/end[enter key]pO

Deletes five lines, searches for end, places the lines underneath, adds a space.

If you have VimRuby installed, I believe you can use % to jump between def and end. In that case, you could say

v%x5jpO

Edit: I defer to spatz on this :P

Answer (score 0):

From line 1, 5ddGp , or 5dd:5p is the most concise/shortest I can think of.

Comment: any way to avoid the line counting in the head problem?

Answer (score 0):

personally, I would go '4dd' then down under bar and press 'p', but I'm not a vim guru